# " server closed the stream without sending trailers" error when calling grpc endpoints over ambassador with TLS

Tags: envoyproxy, ambassador

I'm getting the error "server closed the stream without sending trailers" on the GRPC client side, when calling the GRPC endpoint exposed in Ambassador.

So my stack is :
Client GRPC code -> Ambassador -> grpc-service-envoy -> grpc-service

I can see the request going all the way to grpc-service, and they seem to reach the grpc-service-envoy too.

Note that http transcoded calls are working fine. Just the grpc calls are causing issues.

Any idea what could be wrong here?

envoy conf file:

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: mix-api-listener
    address:
      socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 51051 }
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          stat_prefix: grpc_json
          codec_type: AUTO
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/swagger-ui"}
                route: { cluster: swagger-backend-services, timeout: { seconds: 1500 } }
              - match: { prefix: "/swagger-resources"}
                route: { cluster: swagger-backend-services, timeout: { seconds: 1500 } }
              - match: { prefix: "/v2"}
                route: { cluster: swagger-backend-services, timeout: { seconds: 1500 } }
              - match: { prefix: "/", grpc: {} }
                route: { cluster: grpc-backend-services, timeout: { seconds: 120 } }
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.grpc_json_transcoder
            config:
              proto_descriptor: "/data/mix-api.pb"
              services: ["mix.api.MixAPI"]
              print_options:
                add_whitespace: true
                always_print_primitive_fields: true
                always_print_enums_as_ints: false
                preserve_proto_field_names: false
          - name: envoy.router

  clusters:
  - name: grpc-backend-services
    connect_timeout: 150s
    type: logical_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: ${GRPC_HOST}
        port_value: 9090
  - name: swagger-backend-services
    connect_timeout: 150s
    type: logical_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: ${GRPC_HOST}
        port_value: 8080
```

envoy logs:

```
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:508] [C6] socket event: 3
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:616] [C6] write ready
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:546] [C6] read ready. dispatch_buffered_data=false
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/raw_buffer_socket.cc:25] [C6] read returns: 2070
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/raw_buffer_socket.cc:39] [C6] read error: Resource temporarily unavailable
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:535] [C6] parsing 2070 bytes
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:768] [C6] message begin
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][debug][http] [source/common/http/conn_manager_impl.cc:225] [C6] new stream
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=host value=mix-api.dev.cd4.crt.nuance.com:443
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=content-type value=application/grpc
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=user-agent value=grpc-go/1.31.1
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=te value=trailers
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=grpc-client value=evans
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=authorization value=Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InB1YmxpYzoxYWI2YzUxMC00OGEwLTRiZDUtYmZiNy1mOTY2YzFmMDc1MGQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOltdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJtaXgtcG9ydGFsLWNsaWVudCIsImV4cCI6MTYwNzYyNzkyOCwiZXh0Ijp7InN1Yl9pc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi5jZDQuY3J0Lm51YW5jZS5jb20vYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvbWl4IiwidGVuYW50IjoibWl4In0sImlhdCI6MTYwNzYyNzAyOCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hdXRoLWRldi5jZDQuY3J0Lm51YW5jZS5jb20vIiwianRpIjoiYmU5YzJkZDYtZDQzOS00Y2E2LWIzNTUtYzMwMzRlMjg3MjVhIiwibmJmIjoxNjA3NjI3MDI4LCJzY3AiOlsibWl4LWFwaSJdLCJzdWIiOiJkNjE4ZTFmMC0zODA4LTQ4OTItYWUyYi03YmZiNDQ4YmQ5MWUifQ.bi6p0r0Zb6ERCo4SXYnj6g6GjK0ZhCMdhqqorbfGE9bgnU4spo0hlGGnGJ8lNY6jhO7qYkPqhvZBX2UmvFeTCfufzIFvYKF2ZQ4j8ONte8LEtAM8RghuQ_WrvMvjF26NhsrCpELkhh2xzvCFt3WbbS6v5w1CyNi-FsB3PJhOgY1UgP0_Iw6quzPz_HHUs6uX3W9J4zUYlKhfqztuAHp01Pzo5DreYX5xjh5ogueye5IlKFDQFZE8FxZMNnXUGJR7nH_s5GkbMS-b-GNheHlNBBQ8QoXiMLUgq6MixcmdK_jvjAnJe8pr3GEDgo71lEvUq7bzL40_Px7kXnJmxg2hgHk7KMrMqyz0009hN0phyPRNF9OtJ-DUxFSvckhUQjddPAx55YQdCJf8AeK3wTwajDNppSZV_Ncbd-GHzf6J4dGNEZBdPDaerhG7Zmu_WF66DJ95luwC8dR0Rh2HYbbURCME0GcbOIxEr7jHnlEBgFbfFUrmuN5qO5y1oqNpe5i1r_9SsvWLZHQYCtlWi1K89zcsN4UOGZbXXy0-AgSAFvU4h3lV73EVJRzgPXoyZQEnHmGAEfUsvfez-JZvOZWsJ86PbK_OQXoxfxLwU5nwAwlspD4JqFgYVSbQUEZ7Tp4TmOqoEnO3QZkY4j49TN70Ip4GrDpOauFNnH_53U5Z05I
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=x-forwarded-for value=10.3.195.67
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=x-forwarded-proto value=https
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=x-envoy-internal value=true
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=x-request-id value=e31b694f-c0d6-9d40-a9ef-01517b1184d3
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=x-nuance-client-id value=mix-portal-client
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=x-nuance-client-id-iss value=https://auth-dev.cd4.crt.nuance.com/
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=x-nuance-client-scopes value=[mix-api]
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=x-nuance-tenant-id value=mix
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=x-nuance-user-id value=d618e1f0-3808-4892-ae2b-7bfb448bd91e
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=x-nuance-user-id-iss value=https://dev.cd4.crt.nuance.com/auth/realms/mix
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=x-envoy-expected-rq-timeout-ms value=120000
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=x-b3-traceid value=6dc62f223a5d9a9a4a0a25f9e2ed22bf
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=x-b3-spanid value=8778e830a199e676
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=x-b3-parentspanid value=4a0a25f9e2ed22bf
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=x-b3-sampled value=1
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:632] [C6] onHeadersCompleteBase
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:470] [C6] completed header: key=transfer-encoding value=chunked
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:874] [C6] Server: onHeadersComplete size=22
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][debug][http] [source/common/http/conn_manager_impl.cc:837] [C6][S7575434646215072185] request headers complete (end_stream=false):
':authority', 'mix-api.dev.cd4.crt.nuance.com:443'
':path', '/mix.api.MixAPI/GetVersion'
':method', 'POST'
'content-type', 'application/grpc'
'user-agent', 'grpc-go/1.31.1'
'te', 'trailers'
'grpc-client', 'evans'
'authorization', 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InB1YmxpYzoxYWI2YzUxMC00OGEwLTRiZDUtYmZiNy1mOTY2YzFmMDc1MGQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOltdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJtaXgtcG9ydGFsLWNsaWVudCIsImV4cCI6MTYwNzYyNzkyOCwiZXh0Ijp7InN1Yl9pc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi5jZDQuY3J0Lm51YW5jZS5jb20vYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvbWl4IiwidGVuYW50IjoibWl4In0sImlhdCI6MTYwNzYyNzAyOCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hdXRoLWRldi5jZDQuY3J0Lm51YW5jZS5jb20vIiwianRpIjoiYmU5YzJkZDYtZDQzOS00Y2E2LWIzNTUtYzMwMzRlMjg3MjVhIiwibmJmIjoxNjA3NjI3MDI4LCJzY3AiOlsibWl4LWFwaSJdLCJzdWIiOiJkNjE4ZTFmMC0zODA4LTQ4OTItYWUyYi03YmZiNDQ4YmQ5MWUifQ.bi6p0r0Zb6ERCo4SXYnj6g6GjK0ZhCMdhqqorbfGE9bgnU4spo0hlGGnGJ8lNY6jhO7qYkPqhvZBX2UmvFeTCfufzIFvYKF2ZQ4j8ONte8LEtAM8RghuQ_WrvMvjF26NhsrCpELkhh2xzvCFt3WbbS6v5w1CyNi-FsB3PJhOgY1UgP0_Iw6quzPz_HHUs6uX3W9J4zUYlKhfqztuAHp01Pzo5DreYX5xjh5ogueye5IlKFDQFZE8FxZMNnXUGJR7nH_s5GkbMS-b-GNheHlNBBQ8QoXiMLUgq6MixcmdK_jvjAnJe8pr3GEDgo71lEvUq7bzL40_Px7kXnJmxg2hgHk7KMrMqyz0009hN0phyPRNF9OtJ-DUxFSvckhUQjddPAx55YQdCJf8AeK3wTwajDNppSZV_Ncbd-GHzf6J4dGNEZBdPDaerhG7Zmu_WF66DJ95luwC8dR0Rh2HYbbURCME0GcbOIxEr7jHnlEBgFbfFUrmuN5qO5y1oqNpe5i1r_9SsvWLZHQYCtlWi1K89zcsN4UOGZbXXy0-AgSAFvU4h3lV73EVJRzgPXoyZQEnHmGAEfUsvfez-JZvOZWsJ86PbK_OQXoxfxLwU5nwAwlspD4JqFgYVSbQUEZ7Tp4TmOqoEnO3QZkY4j49TN70Ip4GrDpOauFNnH_53U5Z05I'
'x-forwarded-for', '10.3.195.67'
'x-forwarded-proto', 'https'
'x-envoy-internal', 'true'
'x-request-id', 'e31b694f-c0d6-9d40-a9ef-01517b1184d3'
'x-nuance-client-id', 'mix-portal-client'
'x-nuance-client-id-iss', 'https://auth-dev.cd4.crt.nuance.com/'
'x-nuance-client-scopes', '[mix-api]'
'x-nuance-tenant-id', 'mix'
'x-nuance-user-id', 'd618e1f0-3808-4892-ae2b-7bfb448bd91e'
'x-nuance-user-id-iss', 'https://dev.cd4.crt.nuance.com/auth/realms/mix'
'x-envoy-expected-rq-timeout-ms', '120000'
'x-b3-traceid', '6dc62f223a5d9a9a4a0a25f9e2ed22bf'
'x-b3-spanid', '8778e830a199e676'
'x-b3-parentspanid', '4a0a25f9e2ed22bf'
'x-b3-sampled', '1'
'transfer-encoding', 'chunked'

[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/filter_manager.cc:463] [C6][S7575434646215072185] decode headers called: filter=0x36433e962240 status=0
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][debug][router] [source/common/router/router.cc:429] [C6][S7575434646215072185] cluster 'grpc-backend-services' match for URL '/mix.api.MixAPI/GetVersion'
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][debug][router] [source/common/router/router.cc:586] [C6][S7575434646215072185] router decoding headers:
':authority', 'mix-api.dev.cd4.crt.nuance.com:443'
':path', '/mix.api.MixAPI/GetVersion'
':method', 'POST'
':scheme', 'http'
'content-type', 'application/grpc'
'user-agent', 'grpc-go/1.31.1'
'te', 'trailers'
'grpc-client', 'evans'
'authorization', 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InB1YmxpYzoxYWI2YzUxMC00OGEwLTRiZDUtYmZiNy1mOTY2YzFmMDc1MGQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOltdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJtaXgtcG9ydGFsLWNsaWVudCIsImV4cCI6MTYwNzYyNzkyOCwiZXh0Ijp7InN1Yl9pc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi5jZDQuY3J0Lm51YW5jZS5jb20vYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvbWl4IiwidGVuYW50IjoibWl4In0sImlhdCI6MTYwNzYyNzAyOCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hdXRoLWRldi5jZDQuY3J0Lm51YW5jZS5jb20vIiwianRpIjoiYmU5YzJkZDYtZDQzOS00Y2E2LWIzNTUtYzMwMzRlMjg3MjVhIiwibmJmIjoxNjA3NjI3MDI4LCJzY3AiOlsibWl4LWFwaSJdLCJzdWIiOiJkNjE4ZTFmMC0zODA4LTQ4OTItYWUyYi03YmZiNDQ4YmQ5MWUifQ.bi6p0r0Zb6ERCo4SXYnj6g6GjK0ZhCMdhqqorbfGE9bgnU4spo0hlGGnGJ8lNY6jhO7qYkPqhvZBX2UmvFeTCfufzIFvYKF2ZQ4j8ONte8LEtAM8RghuQ_WrvMvjF26NhsrCpELkhh2xzvCFt3WbbS6v5w1CyNi-FsB3PJhOgY1UgP0_Iw6quzPz_HHUs6uX3W9J4zUYlKhfqztuAHp01Pzo5DreYX5xjh5ogueye5IlKFDQFZE8FxZMNnXUGJR7nH_s5GkbMS-b-GNheHlNBBQ8QoXiMLUgq6MixcmdK_jvjAnJe8pr3GEDgo71lEvUq7bzL40_Px7kXnJmxg2hgHk7KMrMqyz0009hN0phyPRNF9OtJ-DUxFSvckhUQjddPAx55YQdCJf8AeK3wTwajDNppSZV_Ncbd-GHzf6J4dGNEZBdPDaerhG7Zmu_WF66DJ95luwC8dR0Rh2HYbbURCME0GcbOIxEr7jHnlEBgFbfFUrmuN5qO5y1oqNpe5i1r_9SsvWLZHQYCtlWi1K89zcsN4UOGZbXXy0-AgSAFvU4h3lV73EVJRzgPXoyZQEnHmGAEfUsvfez-JZvOZWsJ86PbK_OQXoxfxLwU5nwAwlspD4JqFgYVSbQUEZ7Tp4TmOqoEnO3QZkY4j49TN70Ip4GrDpOauFNnH_53U5Z05I'
'x-forwarded-for', '10.3.195.67'
'x-forwarded-proto', 'https'
'x-request-id', 'e31b694f-c0d6-9d40-a9ef-01517b1184d3'
'x-nuance-client-id', 'mix-portal-client'
'x-nuance-client-id-iss', 'https://auth-dev.cd4.crt.nuance.com/'
'x-nuance-client-scopes', '[mix-api]'
'x-nuance-tenant-id', 'mix'
'x-nuance-user-id', 'd618e1f0-3808-4892-ae2b-7bfb448bd91e'
'x-nuance-user-id-iss', 'https://dev.cd4.crt.nuance.com/auth/realms/mix'
'x-envoy-expected-rq-timeout-ms', '120000'
'x-b3-traceid', '6dc62f223a5d9a9a4a0a25f9e2ed22bf'
'x-b3-spanid', '8778e830a199e676'
'x-b3-parentspanid', '4a0a25f9e2ed22bf'
'x-b3-sampled', '1'
'x-envoy-internal', 'true'

[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][debug][pool] [source/common/conn_pool/conn_pool_base.cc:174] [C7] using existing connection
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][debug][pool] [source/common/conn_pool/conn_pool_base.cc:126] [C7] creating stream
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][debug][router] [source/common/router/upstream_request.cc:357] [C6][S7575434646215072185] pool ready
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http2] [source/common/http/http2/codec_impl.cc:914] [C7] about to send frame type=1, flags=4
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http2] [source/common/http/http2/codec_impl.cc:941] [C7] send data: bytes=1132
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:429] [C7] writing 1132 bytes, end_stream false
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http2] [source/common/http/http2/codec_impl.cc:843] [C7] sent frame type=1
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/filter_manager.cc:463] [C6][S7575434646215072185] decode headers called: filter=0x36433e909800 status=1
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:955] [C6] body size=7
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/filter_manager.cc:594] [C6][S7575434646215072185] decode data called: filter=0x36433e962240 status=0
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][router] [source/common/router/upstream_request.cc:224] [C6][S7575434646215072185] proxying 7 bytes
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:429] [C7] writing 16 bytes, end_stream false
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http2] [source/common/http/http2/codec_impl.cc:843] [C7] sent frame type=0
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/filter_manager.cc:594] [C6][S7575434646215072185] decode data called: filter=0x36433e909800 status=3
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:745] [C6] message complete
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:311] [C6] readDisable: disable=true disable_count=0 state=0 buffer_length=2070
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][debug][http] [source/common/http/filter_manager.cc:721] [C6][S7575434646215072185] request end stream
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/filter_manager.cc:594] [C6][S7575434646215072185] decode data called: filter=0x36433e962240 status=0
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][router] [source/common/router/upstream_request.cc:224] [C6][S7575434646215072185] proxying 0 bytes
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:429] [C7] writing 9 bytes, end_stream false
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http2] [source/common/http/http2/codec_impl.cc:843] [C7] sent frame type=0
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/filter_manager.cc:594] [C6][S7575434646215072185] decode data called: filter=0x36433e909800 status=3
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/http1/codec_impl_legacy.cc:562] [C6] parsed 2070 bytes
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:508] [C6] socket event: 2
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:616] [C6] write ready
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:508] [C7] socket event: 2
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:616] [C7] write ready
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.616][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/raw_buffer_socket.cc:68] [C7] write returns: 1157
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:508] [C7] socket event: 3
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:616] [C7] write ready
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:546] [C7] read ready. dispatch_buffered_data=false
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/raw_buffer_socket.cc:25] [C7] read returns: 126
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/raw_buffer_socket.cc:39] [C7] read error: Resource temporarily unavailable
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][http2] [source/common/http/http2/codec_impl.cc:636] [C7] dispatching 126 bytes
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][http2] [source/common/http/http2/codec_impl.cc:711] [C7] about to recv frame type=1, flags=4
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][http2] [source/common/http/http2/codec_impl.cc:735] [C7] recv frame type=1
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][debug][router] [source/common/router/router.cc:1178] [C6]grpc-service-envoy[S7575434646215072185] upstream headers complete: end_stream=false
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/filter_manager.cc:966] [C6][S7575434646215072185] encode headers called: filter=0x36433ea3f630 status=0
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][debug][http] [source/common/http/conn_manager_impl.cc:1435] [C6][S7575434646215072185] encoding headers via codec (end_stream=false):
':status', '200'
'content-type', 'application/grpc'
'grpc-encoding', 'identity'
'grpc-accept-encoding', 'gzip'
'x-envoy-upstream-service-time', '30'
'date', 'Thu, 10 Dec 2020 19:11:11 GMT'
'server', 'envoy'

[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:429] [C6] writing 219 bytes, end_stream false
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][http2] [source/common/http/http2/codec_impl.cc:711] [C7] about to recv frame type=0, flags=0
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][http2] [source/common/http/http2/codec_impl.cc:735] [C7] recv frame type=0
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/filter_manager.cc:1122] [C6][S7575434646215072185] encode data called: filter=0x36433ea3f630 status=0
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/conn_manager_impl.cc:1444] [C6][S7575434646215072185] encoding data via codec (size=94 end_stream=false)
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:429] [C6] writing 100 bytes, end_stream false
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][http2] [source/common/http/http2/codec_impl.cc:711] [C7] about to recv frame type=1, flags=5
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][http2] [source/common/http/http2/codec_impl.cc:735] [C7] recv frame type=1
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][debug][client] [source/common/http/codec_client.cc:109] [C7] response complete
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][main] [source/common/event/dispatcher_impl.cc:192] item added to deferred deletion list (size=1)
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][debug][pool] [source/common/conn_pool/conn_pool_base.cc:151] [C7] destroying stream: 0 remaining
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][http] [source/common/http/filter_manager.cc:1170] [C6][S7575434646215072185] encode trailers called: filter=0x36433ea3f630 status=0
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][debug][http] [source/common/http/conn_manager_impl.cc:1451] [C6][S7575434646215072185] encoding trailers via codec:
'grpc-status', '0'

[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:429] [C6] writing 5 bytes, end_stream false
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:311] [C6] readDisable: disable=false disable_count=1 state=0 buffer_length=0
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][main] [source/common/event/dispatcher_impl.cc:192] item added to deferred deletion list (size=2)
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][debug][http2] [source/common/http/http2/codec_impl.cc:964] [C7] stream closed: 0
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][main] [source/common/event/dispatcher_impl.cc:192] item added to deferred deletion list (size=3)
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][http2] [source/common/http/http2/codec_impl.cc:663] [C7] dispatched 126 bytes
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][main] [source/common/event/dispatcher_impl.cc:83] clearing deferred deletion list (size=3)
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:508] [C7] socket event: 2
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:616] [C7] write ready
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:508] [C6] socket event: 2
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:616] [C6] write ready
[2020-12-10 19:11:11.647][36][trace][connection] [source/common/network/raw_buffer_socket.cc:68] [C6] write returns: 324
```

Comment: BTW, Ambassador only logs a 200 status entry for these requests

Comment: @gheorgi did you found a work around? what is mentioned in the issue is not very clear, seems to be envoy related, since I have the exact same problem as you

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem was actually caused by an Ambassador glitch. Details on the ambassador issue can be found here: https://github.com/datawire/ambassador/issues/3112